# How to split JS arguments and ignore \'

Tags: javascript, node.js, split

I'm separating Arguments of a file and putting them into DeepL's Api. My Problem is that some of the Translations on the Input site have a few Arguments which shouldn't be parsed like: 
e.g.:

'Hello this should be parsed, and this what\'s having a \' in it shouldn't." => "Translation".

To conclude this: I haven't a way to ignore ' for separating in JS when there's a backslash in it like: \'
This results in having broken Arguments detected...

I tried counting the apostrophes in the line and dividing them by two and say: e.g. the line has 4 apostrophes = 4/2 which means 2 for each argument.
2nd example: 6 apostrophes = 6/2 = 3 which means 3 for each argument.

This sounds like a good way of dealing with the problem but I didn't find a good way of implementing it. Additionally this would require me to reattach arguments which got separated or separate just those after e.g. 3 apostrophes... I'm a bit confused here ...

```
var separate = line.split("'");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.replace()` to remove `\`:

```js
const input = `What\'s in goin\' on?`;

console.log(
  input.replace("\\", "").split("'")
)
```

EDIT: remove backslash and aphostrophe:

```js
    const input = `What\'s in goin' on?`;

    console.log(
      input.replace(/\\?'/g, "")
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for that Answer. But how can I remove the apostrophe behind the backslash and the backslash?

Comment: @TorstenHögel behind or after?

Comment: I mean from 'There\'s an apple!' to 'Theres an apple'

Comment: @TorstenHögel oh I see, you could use this regex `/\\?'/g`, I've just updated my post